# Simplify php validation of array from form-input

Tags: php, validation

I'm creating a page where you can save your predictions for soccermatches. 
Every week there are 9 matches and a user can post his prediction for a match via a form. 
The result of this form will result in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [week] => 12
    [game_id_1] => 28
    [game_1_home] => 2
    [game_1_away] => 2
    [game_id_2] => 29
    [game_2_home] => 2
    [game_2_away] => 1
    [game_id_3] => 31
    [game_3_home] => 4
    [game_3_away] => 0
    [game_id_4] => 30
    [game_4_home] => 2
    [game_4_away] => 0
    [game_id_5] => 32
    [game_5_home] => 0
    [game_5_away] => 2
    [game_id_6] => 33
    [game_6_home] => 1
    [game_6_away] => 0
    [game_id_7] => 35
    [game_7_home] => 1
    [game_7_away] => 1
    [game_id_8] => 34
    [game_8_home] => 2
    [game_8_away] => 4
    [game_id_9] => 36
    [game_9_home] => 3
    [game_9_away] => 0
)
```

I already wrote a validation part for the first match but instead of copying this 8 times I think this can go much easier.
Anyone an idea how to do this and please give me advice if I can improve this piece of code.

```php
$blnOK = true;
$strResult = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (isset($_POST['game_id_1']) && !empty($_POST['game_1_home']) && !empty($_POST['game_1_away'])) 
    //check if the posts are not empty, then put in variables
    {
        $strGame_id_1 = $_POST['game_id_1'];
        $strGame_1_home = $_POST['game_1_home'];
        $strGame_1_away = $_POST['game_1_away'];

        //Check if strings are numeric
        if ((ctype_digit($strGame_1_home)) && (ctype_digit($strGame_1_away)))
        {
            //Check if prediction already exists in database for user
            $strQueryPrediction = "SELECT count(id) amount FROM prediction where player_id = 1 and game_id = $strGame_id_1";
            $resultQueryPrediction = mysql_query ($strQueryPrediction);

            $intPredictionKnown = mysql_result($resultQueryPrediction, 0);

            if ($intPredictionKnown == 0)
            {
                //NOT KNOWN so INSERT
                $blnOK = executeQuery("INSERT INTO prediction (player_id, game_id, predict_home, predict_away) VALUES (1, $strGame_id_1, $strGame_1_home, $strGame_1_away)", $strErrorText, $db);
                echo "Your prediction is saved";
            }
            else
            {
                //KNOWN so UPDATE
                $blnOK = executeQuery("UPDATE prediction SET predict_home = $strGame_1_home, predict_away = $strGame_1_away WHERE player_id = 1 AND game_id = $strGame_id_1", $strErrorText, $db);
                echo "Your prediction is updated";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $strResult = "Too bad, your prediction could not saved.";
            $blnOK = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Input is empty";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, and arguably should, use a loop to save you copying the code a number of times.  You say there are 9 games, so you can do the following :

```
    $blnOK = true;
$strResult = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['game_id_' . $i]) && !empty($_POST['game_' . $i . '_home']) && !empty($_POST['game_' . $i . '_away'])) 
        //check if the posts are not empty, then put in variables
        {
            $strGame_id = $_POST['game_id_' . $i];
            $strGame_home = $_POST['game_' . $i . '_home'];
            $strGame_away = $_POST['game_' . $i . '_away'];

            //Check if strings are numeric
            if ((ctype_digit($strGame_' . $i . '_home)) && (ctype_digit($strGame_' . $i . '_away)))
            {
                //Check if prediction already exists in database for user
                $strQueryPrediction = "SELECT count(id) amount FROM prediction where player_id = 1 and game_id = $strGame_id";
                $resultQueryPrediction = mysql_query ($strQueryPrediction);

                $intPredictionKnown = mysql_result($resultQueryPrediction, 0);

                if ($intPredictionKnown == 0)
                {
                    //NOT KNOWN so INSERT
                    $blnOK = executeQuery("INSERT INTO prediction (player_id, game_id, predict_home, predict_away) VALUES (1, $strGame_id, $strGame_home, $strGame_away)", $strErrorText, $db);
                    echo "Your prediction is saved";
                }
                else
                {
                    //KNOWN so UPDATE
                    $blnOK = executeQuery("UPDATE prediction SET predict_home = $strGame_home, predict_away = $strGame_away WHERE player_id = 1 AND game_id = $strGame_id", $strErrorText, $db);
                    echo "Your prediction is updated";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $strResult = "Too bad, your prediction could not saved.";
                $blnOK = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
        echo "Input is empty";
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you have to do something multiple times, think of using a loop if possible, or creating a function which you can call multiple times.